# PHP printf out of memory exception

Tags: php, printf, out-of-memory

I have the following code inside two loops.

```
printf(
    '<td style="text-align:center;min-width: 80px;%s%s">'
    , (round($nVolume, 2) < $nVolumeBought) ? 'font-weight:bold;color:red;' : ''
    , ($sDeatail== 'S') ? 'padding: 0;' : ''
  );
```

After printing thousands of rows of my table suddely I get this exception:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 484442112) (tried to allocate 240 bytes)

Comment: It's something else in the loops.

Comment: I tried putting it in a separete function, now the exception still points to the same printf inside the new function.

Comment: The `printf` maybe tried to allocate memory but something else is eating it up causing it to run out.

Comment: Oh! So it´s something else that used a large amount and the printf is the drop that spills the glass? Thanks, I had not thought about that.